# What is fiber bundle matching?

Tags: computational-modeling

In the introduction of this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24747738), the authors mention something called "fiber bundle matching". I'm having trouble understanding if this is an analysis performed on a single subject's data or across subjects. In other words, do you match fibers within one subject to compute a tractography for that subject or do you match fibers across subjects to come up with an "average tractography"? If the former, what is one way to go about computing an average tractography?